# WPF Datagrid dropdown box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, mahapps.metro

I made a datagrid table with combobox, and i dont have any errors, but when i try to click to edit table i get this errors.
I am using mahapps.metro. In another empty project witch i create this code works flawless. So where is problem and how should i fix it

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.
```

And here is problem:     `Error 1   The resource "StatusList" could not be resolved.`

Here is XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgData" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="169,10,10,227">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Subject}" Header="GAME SETTINGS" Width="340"/>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="360">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Status}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox Height="20" IsEditable="True"
                                      ItemsSource="{StaticResource StatusList}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Status}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>

                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
```

And here ic c# code

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            this.Title += "Vuzimir/Normal - 0/2 - 2.0.14.15";
            List<TicketInfo> ticketsList = new List<TicketInfo> 
            {
                new TicketInfo{ Subject="Show Ping", Status="True"},
                new TicketInfo{ Subject="Show Drawings", Status="True"},
                new TicketInfo{ Subject="Send Debug Messages", Status="True"},
                new TicketInfo{ Subject="Enable Default Profile", Status="False"}
            };
            dgData.ItemsSource = ticketsList;


        }
        public class TicketInfo
        {
            public string Subject { get; set; }
            public string Status { get; set; }
        }

        public class StatusList : List<string>
        {
            public StatusList()
            {
                this.Add("True");
                this.Add("False");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is there a `StaticResource` with the Key/name `StatusList` anywhere in your xaml?

Comment: If yes, could you show us that part of the xaml?

Comment: Okay, and yes there is StaticResource, `ItemsSource="{StaticResource StatusList}"`

Comment: That is the place where you are using it, I need you to find and show us the place where you have declared that resource

Answer (score 0):

If You want to bind combobox itemssource then simply use Binding in ItemsSource of combobox.

```
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox Height="20" IsEditable="True"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding StatusList}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Status}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>



   List<TicketInfo> ticketsList = new List<TicketInfo> 
            {
                new TicketInfo{ Subject="Show Ping", Status="True",StatusList=new List<string>(){"True","False"}},
                new TicketInfo{ Subject="Show Drawings", Status="True",StatusList=new List<string>(){"True","False"}},
                new TicketInfo{ Subject="Send Debug Messages", Status="True",StatusList=new List<string>(){"True","False"}},
                new TicketInfo{ Subject="Enable Default Profile", Status="False",StatusList=new List<string>(){"True","False"}}
            };



public class TicketInfo
    {
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        private string _status;
        public string Status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set { _status = value; }
        }
        private List<string> _statusList = new List<string>();
        public List<string> StatusList
        {
            get { return _statusList; }
            set { _statusList = value; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not working, when i do a double click on my combobox there is no selections, its empty...

Comment: List of TicketInfo class is your grid ItemsSource so you must put combobox itemssource list into TicketInfo class. see above code.